# Make all opened document tabs visible

Tags: visual-studio, file, tabs, document, show-hide

I would like to see all files or documents I've opened in Visual Studio. I do not want them to be auto hidden or hidden on overflow.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: VS 2022 v17.4.1 finally has this built in - commenting for visibility since top answers are outdated. See below [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73574180/8026947) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74189196/8026947)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visual Studio has this extension taken from msdn.microsoft.com tested and worked

Simple installation: download, doubleclick to install, restart VS IDE. Then open all the tabs you want they all will be displayed and No hidden.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/EBF6137E-AA2D-4DC9-860A-F04168F11CD7

Dung Le.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a trial version and is rather costly at $49 for a personal license.

Comment: Yes, that is an extension, not a native feature of Visual Studio. Also, it's too expensive for what it does.

Answer (score 134):

One of the built-in option to do so: use pinned tabs.
http://dailydotnettips.com/2016/01/21/persevering-and-separating-the-pinned-tabs-in-visual-studio/

If you don't want to read a external page just for setting:

`Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows -> Show pinned tabs in a seperate row`

It's not completely what you want, but it's free and may be useful.

Comment: It's good to mention that you better save the pin status along with this option if you closed the file unintentionally, same screen with the option: Maintain pin status if document is removed from well.

Comment: Its worth visiting the link. :)

Answer (score 31):

Maybe it's not exactly what you search, but here is a way to at least get a second row for **pinned tabs**.

Effectively get you more space for opened files:

```
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows -> Show pinned tabs in a seperate row
```

Comment: It would be very valuable if some Visual Studio extension developer could write an extension that auto-pins all opened tabs at once or each document on open. Just an idea from Visual Studio user not-extension developer...

Answer (score 7):

In Visual Studio 2022, this issue now has a native solution. Go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows -> Show tabs in multiple rows`. Excess tabs will be shown on additional rows. There doesn't seem to be a limit on how many rows this can use.

Another relevant option that some may find useful; you can choose "Show invisible tabs in italic in tab dropdown menu". The dropdown button is only visible when you hover your mouse near the end of the row of tabs. Showing invisible windows in italics makes it easier to identify windows that are only visible in the overflow menu.

Answer (score 6):

It's worth noting that starting in VS 2019 v16.4, you can now have "vertical tabs" which will list all open tabs vertically, making it easy to see all open files.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-window-layouts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#vertical-document-tabs

Answer (score 4):

For those using Visual Studio 2022, check the *"Show tabs in multiple rows"* setting in *Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows* section.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### For Visual Studio Code

If you want to see all the opened tabs,

you can simply on `wrap tabs` option in the VS Code settings

```
settings > User > Workbench > Editor > Wrap Tabs
```

Comment: I wanted exact same 
and answer provided seems working fine for me. Not sure why it was down-voted
https://app.box.com/s/6ys5knj7inpiwpd9dmq8zexl5jw9iu3j

Comment: Because it refers to VS Code, not Visual Studio

Comment: ah got it @zola25